# Huawei IAP - Currency conversion is not correct

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-iap

In Huawei HMS services, i have integrated IAP kit in my application. IAP currency configured as INR, however for the region Cambodia (KH)-the converted currency value with respect to the pack is incorrect.

In my AppGallery console, product management page, the conversion is 11.99 for KHR-Cambodian currency. But the settlement the conversion is different.
Please can somebody check and let me know how to set conversion correct.

Answer (score 1):

Select a country or region and its currency to be displayed by default, set Default price (tax included), and select a sorting rule. Then, select the countries and regions for which you want to convert prices based on exchange rates and click Convert prices to calculate their local prices.

For details , please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-create-product-0000001099854866

Please Note:

After you click Convert prices, local prices for the selected countries and regions are calculated based on exchange rates and conversion rules.
You can also manually change a product price for a specified country or region on the list as required.
If a message displays, indicating that no exchange rate is found when you convert the price for a country or region, you need to manually enter the product price.
Huawei will update the exchange rates every day but will not update the product prices you have saved. You need to manually update the prices as required.
Click this link https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/start/merchant-service-0000001053025967#section154132916309 to view tax rates of different countries and regions.
[image]